# Import works, but why is require not working?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I am using webpack to build a simple project, in `main.js`.  If I use `import` to import `app.js`, the result works well. However, if I use `require` the vue template won't show on the page.

I thought Babel compiles the `import` to `require`; if so, why is `require` not working here?

The result of using require:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>  
</head>
<body>
    <!--function(e,n,r,o){return Fe(t,e,n,r,o,!0)}-->
    <h1>123</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>  
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <h1>123</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
const Vue = require("vue");
const router = require('vue-router')
// const app = require('./app.vue')
import app from './app.vue'


new Vue({
el: "#app",
data: {},
render: el => el(app),
// router
})
```

webpack.config.js

```
const htmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')


module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, "./src/main.js"),

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "./dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, use: "babel-loader", exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.vue$/, use: "vue-loader" }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new htmlPlugin({
      minify: {
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
      },
      hash: true,
      template: "./src/index.html"
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    // extensions: [ '.vue'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
    }
  },
};
```

app.js

```
<template>
<div class="app-contianer">
    <h1>test</h1>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
    };
  }
}
</script>
<style lang="css" scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: the last file is *app.vue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require` and `import` are different in how they access the imported object.

```
import app from './app.vue'
```

This line *actually* means this, and this should work just the same as the `import`:

```
const app = require('./app.vue').default
```

---

For completeness' sake, this line:

```
const app = require('./app.vue')
```

Would be equivalent to:

```
import * as app from './app.vue'
```